# Android activity lifecycle question: When to commit GlobalPreferences

Tags: android, activity-lifecycle

I have a bunch of user preferences that are saved in a singleton object in my application. A sample model looks like this -

```
public class UserContext {
    public static final String WEBSRV_IP = "TRIMMED";
    public static UserContext instance;
    // Contains username, password, if they're valid etc.
    private LoginDataModel loginModel; 
    private ArrayList<FacilityDataModel> model;
    private FilterDataModel filters;

    private UserContext()
    {

    }

    public UserContext getInstance()
    {
        if(instance == null) {
            instance = new UserContext();
        }
        return instance;
    }   
    // Getters and setters
}
```

So now, as the user goes through the application, I have a bunch of Activities that are created, go through their life cycle, utilize these variables and finish. (For example, in `onStart()` method, I check if the user is logged in before presenting the activity).

My question is, Android docs seem to recommend me to back up any context related data in my `onPause()` method. But `onPause()` also gets called every time I create a new Activity myself and it seems to be wasteful to back all the GlobalVariables up, only to restore them in the next activity's `onStart()` method. Is there a way to determine if the whole application has entered the background instead ? If not, when do you actually save all your Globals?

Thanks, 
Teja.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I save preferences (with SharedPreferences.Editor.commit()) at the moment the preference value is determined, whether by the user or by the application code.  I haven't yet come across a scenario when delaying saving preferences until sometime after they were determined made sense.

Comment: I would tend to agree with this as well, though I've had experience when updating several things causes a bit of a slow down.

Comment: Ah.  Then that may be a scenario I haven't yet come across that does suggest a different solution.  What was causing the slow down?  Were many values being persisted at once?  Were there hundreds or thousands of saved values?

Comment: hundreds yes, thousands no. I should have qualified that a little more, it was before discovering that an SQLite database made more sense for storing long lists of things. For general settings... SharedPreferences makes the most sense.

Answer (score 1):

I think each application's case is going to be different.  onPause() isn't a hateful idea if you need to save the state of that activity.  What if the user moves to another of your own activities and then hits the home button?  Your application will transition to stopped via onStop().  If they re-start your application there's a reasonable expectation (maybe) that the previous state was retained.

I save them when it makes sense to save them.  For instance, I have an SMS application in which I let the user save the last message sent.  I save their last message when the click send.  I do nothing onPause() or onStop(), but I get everything done when the user would expect it to be done.

Developers traditionally hate if-logic, but a wise friend always reminds me, "if-logic is in the mind of the user."  If I do this then this will happen ... in my case; if I send a message my message will be saved.

Answer (score 0):

The only time onPause() is called and onStop() is NOT called... is if your activity is still actually visible beneath another activity that has only partially obscured it. Most of the time, onStop() will also be called, and if you know in your own activities structures you will always be completely obscuring each other activity, i would consider saving in onStop() and restoring in onStart().

Also remember, generally speaking whatever you save in onPause() should be restored in onResume(). What is saved in onStop() should probably be restored in onStart(). If onPause() occurs but onStop() does not... onStart() will not be called.

I should add as well that I agree with Bill Mote's statement, that you should save things when it makes sense to. Once you've got a solid understanding of the Activity Lifecycle framework, you can generally make a good choice.

Comment: Hmm, having trouble thinking about "Activities" as opposed to "Application" in the iOS world.

Comment: I'm not familiar with iOS unfortunately... but the way to think about it is an Application includes all of the Activities that you create in your package. Generally, although not always, you'll have one of those Activities that is declared in the Manifest to be the main launch point (you'll see this as in the <intent-filter> for that activity).