# When to save SharedPreferences?

Tags: android, sharedpreferences, activity-lifecycle

I want to save some small data structures (~1kB total), as well as the user's preferences, while my app is closed.  The settings are modified only in my PreferenceActivity, but the data structures are modified in pretty much every activity.  I've extended `Application` and made all the data structures and preferences static.  I've then tried saving to SharedPreferences in my application class's `onTerminate()` and loading it again in `onCreate()`.  However, `onTerminate()`'s  [documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Application.html#onTerminate%28%29) states that "It will never be called on a production Android device, where processes are removed by simply killing them".

Answers to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5733043/android-activity-lifecycle-question-when-to-commit-globalpreferences) suggest saving to SharedPreferences in the `onStop()` method of each activity modifying their data.  Will this guarantee that the data is saved in *all* cases?  Is there a way to avoid the waste of saving every time the user transitions between activities (or should I even care)?

Comment: can't you simply make a method in your `Application` class to do all the sharedPrefs saving and then call it from an `Activity` when you want?

Comment: Yes, I could make a static method, but where should I call it within the activity lifecycle?

Comment: well you said "while your app is closed" so i'd imagine in `onDestroy` of the last `Activity` that the user will see. or maybe one of those "Are you sure you want to leave?" `Dialogs`.

Comment: The issue is that the user could leave from any activity (e.g. for a phone call), so there's a fair bit of waste.

Comment: `onDestroy()` is not guaranteed to be called while `onStop()` may be called after your next activity starts, so `onPause()` might be the best place.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would honestly just save in the `onPause()` of each activity as is recommended by Android (i.e. when you write an email notice how the draft is saved when the app pauses, such as if the screen turns off). Unless you notice that it is causing lags/delays, it probably won't matter too much.

*If you do* notice lags with this "autosave" method, then you should probably have some sort of "Save" functionality implemented in each activity, which could, for example, entail using a `ProgressDialog` / `AsyncTask` combination.

Comment: If you use `apply()` instead of `commit()` it shouldn't cause any delay in the UI thread.